# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 reference linker error

Tags: c++, undefined-symbol

So I've run into this compiling error when I put the following:

bash-3.2$ g++ -o a *.cpp

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "set_function::set_function(int)", referenced from:
      _main in ccezs7Gk.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

but it seems as though everything is right in my files as far as referencing. Maybe I'm missing something?

```
//
//  hw1_sets.cpp
//
//

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "hw1.h"

using namespace std;

void set_function::assign()                                        //Assign function
{
    cin >> set_function::sets;
    cout << set_function::sets << endl;
    int i;
    if(sets == "R")                                    //if user inputs R
    {

        for(i=0; i<13; i++)                                       //for loop inputting number into R set
        {
            cin >> R[i];
//            return R[i];
        }

    }
    else if (sets == "S")                             //if user inputs S
    {
        for(i=0; i<13; i++)                                     //for loop inputting number into S set
        {
            cin >> S[i];
//            return S[i];
        }
    }
    else if (sets == "T")                                          //if user inputs T
    {
        for(i=0; i<13; i++)                                     //for loop inputting number into T set
        {
            cin >> T[i];
//            return T[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "This set does not exist! Try again!" << endl;
    }

    cout << " set complete" << endl;
    };

void set_function::clear()                                          //Clear function
{
    //find set

    /*cin >> set_function::set;
     cout << set_function::set << endl;
     int i;
     if(set == set_function::R)
     {
        for(i=0; i<13; i++)
        {
            //clear R values
        }
     }
     else if (set == set_function.S)
     {
        for(i=0; i<13; i++)
        {
            //clear S values
        }
     }
     else if (set == T)
     {
        for(i=0; i<13; i++)
        {
            //clear T values
        }
     }

    //remove all values*/
}

void set_function::unionn()                                         //Union function
{
    //for loop from 0 to 12 (through all elements)
    //if set1[x] or set2[x] = 1
        //solution[x]=1
    //else
        //solution[x]=0

}
void set_function::intersection()                                   //Intersection function
{
    //for loop from 0 to 12 (through all elements)
    //if set1[x] == set2[x]
        //solution[x]=set1[x]
    //else
        //solution[x]=0
}

void set_function::difference()                                     //difference function
{
    //for loop from 0 to 12 (through all elements)
        //set1[x]-set2[x]=solution[x]
}



/*printing the set doesn't work*/
void set_function::print()                                          //print function
{
    /*string setname;
    cin >> setname;
    if (setname = "R")
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<13; i++)
        {
            cout<< R[i] << "-";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (setname = "S")
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<13; i++)
        {
            cout<< S[i] << "-";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (setname = "T")
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<13; i++)
        {
            cout<< T[i] << "-";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    //else if lastdigit
        //end of command or newline*/
}

//exit
```

---

```
//
//  hw1.cpp
//  
//
//
//

#include "hw1.h"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string function;
    set_function sets(27);

    while(1)
    {
        cout << "sets> ";

        cin >> function;

        if(function=="assign")
        {
            sets->assign();
        }
        else if(function=="clear")
        {
            sets->clear();
        }
        else if(function=="union")
        {
            sets->unionn();
        }
        else if(function=="intersection")
        {
            sets->intersection();
        }
        else if(function=="difference")
        {
            sets->difference();
        }
        else if(function=="print")
        {
            sets->print();
        }
        else if(function=="quit")
        {
//            sets->quit();
            return 0;
        }

        else
        {
            cout<<"error"<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
//
//  hw1.h
//  
//
//
//

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class set_function
{    
    private:
        bool R[13];
        bool S[13];
        bool T[13];

    public:
        string sets;
        int values[13];
        /*void r()
        {
            R.resize(13);
        }
        void s()
        {
            S.resize(13);
        }
        void t()
        {
            T.resize(13);
        }*/
        set_function(int a){}
        void assign();
        void clear();
        void unionn();
        void intersection();
        void difference();
        void print();
//        void quit();

};
```

edit (10/3/13 @12:50p): I changed what was commented on and now I get this problem:

```
hw1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
hw1.cpp:28: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘set_function’
hw1.cpp:32: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘set_function’
hw1.cpp:36: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘set_function’
hw1.cpp:40: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘set_function’
hw1.cpp:44: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘set_function’
hw1.cpp:48: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘set_function’
```

edit (10/3/13 @1:23p): Fixed. changed the following:

```
set_function *sets = new set_function(27)
```

to

```
set_function *sets;
sets = new set_function(27);
```

compiles correctly now. Thanks!

Comment: Side note: in the code you posted, you are creating on the heap `sets` (and you forgot to delete it at the end). You can simply create it on the stack using `set_function sets(27);`

Comment: Aslo, don't use this: `sets->set_function::assign();`  Just write `sets->assign();`

Comment: Thanks you guys! Yeah I originally had sets->assign() but I wasn't sure where the linking problem was happening. haha and I'll change the set_function sets issue! Thanks everyone!

Comment: If you use `set_function sets(27);` instead of a pointer, then you're going to use non-pointer notation when accessing it.  i.e. `sets.print()` instead of `sets->print()`.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a compiler error, it's a linker error.  You're getting it because you declared a constructor for your `set_function` class but didn't ever define it.

Comment: Yeah I know it was a linker error, used compiler because it happened as I tried to compile. changed the syntax for clarification.

How would I go about defining it (Probably a simple answer)? So I also compiled it with the -c flag and it compiled fine, but I don't know how to combine the .o files.

Comment: It will still fail if you try to link, even with the `-c` flags.  You need to actually write a constructor if you define one in the class.  The simplest possible solution is to replace the `;` at the end of the `set_function` definition in `hw1.h` with `{}`.

Comment: (deleted comment)since I see what you mean. I changed it, new error is listed as an edit above

Answer (score 1):

So you declare `set_function::set_function(int a)` in `hw1.h`. Then `main.cpp` is correctly compiled as the call to the constructor of `set_function` is correct as found declared in the header file `hw1.h`.

But that function is not implemented anywhere, linking occurs and the call is not resolved.

You should implement it right in the header file or in `hw1.cpp` file.